# jQuery não captura radiobutton personalizado clicado (click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radiobutton

Tenho um HTML simples que

```
<input name="chave_binaria" type="radio" id="radio_39" value="1" class="with-gap radio-col-green" checked>
<label for="radio_39">Esquerda</label>

<input name="chave_binaria" type="radio" id="radio_40" value="2" class="with-gap radio-col-green">
<label for="radio_40">Direita</label>
```

E tenho o seguinte código jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change', 'input[name="chave_binaria"]', function(){

        let binary_key = $('input[name="chave_binaria"]:checked').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: baseURL+'requests/change_binary_key',
            data: {key: binary_key},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(callback){

                if(callback.status == 1){

                    new Noty({
                        type: 'success',
                        text: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Chave binária alterada com sucesso!',
                        timeout: 3000
                    }).show();

                }else{

                    new Noty({
                        type: 'error',
                        text: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Erro ao alterar chave binária. Tente novamente.',
                        timeout: 3000
                    }).show();
                }
            },

            error: function(message){
                console.log('Erro ao alterar chave binária: ', message.responseText);
            }
        });

    });

}); /* ready */
```

Quando clico no **radio button** para dar o checked nele, a função do jQuery que criei não executa. Já tentei usar o **click** na função e também nada. Se eu deixo o radio button da forma "crua" do HTML ele funciona normalmente. O que pode ser?

Comment: Dei um Ctrl+C > Ctrl+V no seu código e está capturando o click no `radio` perfeitamente. Única coisa que alterei foi trocar a função *ajax* por um `console.log('Click capturado');`. Ocorre algum erro no console do seu projeto quando roda o código completo?

Comment: Isso ocorre porque o seu radio é personalizado, você tem que usar o object inspector para ver onde você esta clicando.